# Freemarker: How to write a BigDecimal's value that can be used in a BigDecimal constructor

Tags: freemarker

I would like to use freemarker to generate java code that instantiates a BigDecimal.

The value of the BigDecimal is present at generation time.

the BigDecimal API would work like this:

`BigDecimal copy = new BigDecimal(original.toString());`

Alas, the freemarker magic uses numeric conversion on my value of `original`, so this does not work (in a freemarkter template):

`BigDecimal copy = new BigDecimal("${original?c}");`

None of the numeric conversions (percent, number, computer, ...) works - `c`/`computer` most interestingly, because it outputs `0` if the value becomes too big.

With considerable pain, I might be able to wrap the BigDecimal in another Object that just gives me a `toString` and is not a number, so freemarker might leave its value untouched and my generated BigDecimal is correct, but that's only a last resort.

Maybe there is a way to invoke the `toString()` method and print the result into the target document?

ERRATUM:
*because it outputs 0 if the value becomes too big* should read *because it outputs 0 if the value becomes too small* (see @ddkany's answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** FreeMarker 2.3.32 now supports lossless formatting with `?c`, which is not based on `DecimalFormat`, but mostly on `toString`. To use that, you have to set the `c_format` configuration setting to any other value than its backward compatible default, `"legacy"`. Like setting it to `"JavaScript or JSON"` is fine for most projects (that's also the default if you just set the `incompatible_improvements` configuration setting to 2.3.32). See the fine details of how numers are formatted in the documentation of the `c` built-in: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_number.html#ref_builtin_c

**Old answer, for 2.3.31 and before:**

What FreeMarke does by default is whatever Java's `DecimalFormat` does (for the localized `medium` format by default, again defined by the Java platform).

`?c` uses `new DecimalFormat("0.################")` with fixed `US` locale (and some more symbol adjustments for `INF` and `NaN`). So I don't know how that gives `0` for a huge `BigDecimal` number. Are you sure about that? I guess it was actually a very small number, so it was rounded down. Well, switching to "scientific" format would make more sense then, though.

To have whatever formatting logic you need, you can register your own number formatter like, in this case, `configuration.setCustomNumberFormats(Map.of("toString", new MyToStringTemplateNumberFormatFactory())`, and then you can use `${original?string.@toString}`. Or rather, you can set the `number_format` to `@toString`, and then just use `${original}`.

Comment: Thanks, working through your answer, I realize you are right about the numbers failing to be rendered properly being too small rather than too big. Updating the question.

Comment: Small test for BigDecimal/DecimalFormat shows that DF has problem with E notation.
DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("0.################");
fmt.setParseBigDecimal(true);
System.out.println(fmt.parse(new BigDecimal("100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000").toString()));
System.out.println(fmt.parse(new BigDecimal("0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001").toString()));
System.out.println(fmt.parse(new BigDecimal("1.0E-80").toString()));
System.out.println(new BigDecimal("1.0E-80").toString());

Comment: @fkleedorfer Updated my answer for 2.3.32, where this problem was addressed.